# Signing using PKCS#1v1.5 in python

Tags: python, string, rsa, signature

I was writing a basic code for RSA signing in python. I am following the algorithm ["signing using PKCS#1v1.5" given in this link"](http://www.dimgt.com.au/rsa_alg.html#notation) to write my code.

The problem I'm having is:

1. `str(0xff)` will print as `255` what to do if want to print it as `ff`.
2. `m1=int(EB`) gives error here that string can't be converted to integer

Also see the comments in the code.

```
import base64
import hashlib
import sys

n = 103923750583675917777452723084902275956322321347251369547198561741725160583083214244873468324950694356892627873520290850868687184677774313738345853731914172873201679734133922293223038318576487055717405740516986030705800665383388489578499651714083347835387576319528274700123545962228546255987411521556243948149

e = 65537
d = 17565091249452647225549595093023216057619090797007849313736034124434893324058360379487364521346397323516481360986683274410980788633530769996790469838235089550522885790106853124306578513977869050393094033637670437634572856174875038057195517551596745993052717984365235149738925687601660611790816608095661093629

m= '250887726'
h= hashlib.sha256 (m)
print h

t= '3031300d060960864801650304020105000420' + str(h)
print t
str1=str(00)
print str1
str2=str(01)
print str2
str3=str(0xff)  # it prints as 255 what to do if want to print it as ff
print str3
EB=str1+str2+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str3+str1+str(t)
print 'EB:', EB

m1=int(EB) # it gives error here that string can't be converted to integer                                      

s= pow (m1, d, n)

print 'signature: ',s
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here?

Comment: I want to remove the errors in my code. I have mentioned in the code where the errors are showing up.

Comment: In line m1=int (EB). I want to convert the string EB to integer so i can sign it. But whenever i run the code it gives error invalid literal for int() with base 10.

Comment: It's always best to include the actual question in the text of the question; that makes it a lot clearer. I've edited the question for you (also note how I've removed a lot of extra information that's not needed for this question). P.S. `//` is not used to denote comments in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is my first time posting on this forum. I did not realized that i was making so many mistakes.

Comment: That's okay :-) And Stack Overflow isn't a forum, it's a Question and Answer site (not the same!) See the [tour] and [help].

Answer (score 0):

> str(0xff) will print as 255 what to do if want to print it as ff.

You can use formatting:

```
'{:x}'.format(0xff)
```

> m1=int(EB) gives error here that string can't be converted to integer

Use second argument of int(), which shows in what base your integer is:

```
int('ff', 16)
```